# eve app deployment errors can anyone help me to fix it

Tags: python, wsgi, eve

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953008 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950] mod_wsgi (pid=3230): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApps/FlaskApps.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953045 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950] mod_wsgi (pid=3230): Exception occurred processing WSGI script  '/var/www/FlaskApps/FlaskApps.wsgi'.

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953065 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953079 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950]   File "/var/www/FlaskApps/FlaskApps.wsgi", line 8, in

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953126 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950]     from run import app as application

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953136 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950]   File "/var/www/FlaskApps/PlagiarismDefenderApp/run.py", line 28, in

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953165 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950]     app = Eve()

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953173 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 139, in **init**

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953371 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950]     self.validate_domain_struct()

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953382 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 252, in validate_domain_struct

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953395 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950]     raise ConfigException('DOMAIN dictionary missing or wrong.')

[Sat Apr 09 18:27:29.953408 2016] [:error] [pid 3230:tid 140635784853248] [client 103.14.196.22:53950] ConfigException: DOMAIN dictionary missing or wrong.

home.py file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from eve import Eve

if 'PORT' in os.environ:
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT'))
    host = '0.0.0.0'
else:
    port = 5000
    host = '127.0.0.1'

app = Eve()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=host, port=port)
```

settins.py file

```
import os

MONGO_HOST = os.environ.get('MONGO_HOST', 'localhost')
MONGO_PORT = os.environ.get('MONGO_PORT', 27017)
MONGO_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MONGO_USERNAME', 'user')
MONGO_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MONGO_PASSWORD', 'user')
MONGO_DBNAME = os.environ.get('MONGO_DBNAME', 'evedemo')

RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']

ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']

CACHE_CONTROL = 'max-age=20'
CACHE_EXPIRES = 20

people = {
    # 'title' tag used in item links.
    'item_title': 'person',


    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
        'field': 'lastname'
    },

    'schema': {
        'firstname': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 1,
            'maxlength': 10,
        },
        'lastname': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 1,
            'maxlength': 15,
            'required': True,
        },
        'role': {
            'type': 'list',
            'allowed': ["author", "contributor", "copy"],
        },
        # An embedded 'strongly-typed' dictionary.
        'location': {
            'type': 'dict',
            'schema': {
                'address': {'type': 'string'},
                'city': {'type': 'string'}
            },
        },
        'born': {
            'type': 'datetime',
        },
    }
}

works = {
    'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
    'cache_expires': 10,

    'schema': {
        'title': {
            'type': 'string',
            'required': True,
        },
        'description': {
            'type': 'string',
        },
        'owner': {
            'type': 'objectid',
            'required': True,
            'data_relation': {
                'resource': 'people',
                'embeddable': True
            },
        },
    }
}

DOMAIN = {
    'people': people,
    'works': works,
}
```

/var/www/FlaskApps/FlaskApps.wsgi

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApps/PlagiarismDefenderApp/")

# home points to the home.py file
from home import app as application
application.secret_key = "somesecretsessionkey"
```

Comment: Your `DOMAIN` dict is OK, I've tested in my environment with gevent WSGI server. I saw this problem once, I will try to remember what it was.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `settings` path that the Eve app is using. Check if it matches your `settings.py`. This error can be raised if you point the app to a wrong settings.py path.

Also, I guess it's a typo but you wrote `settins.py`. If that is correct, there's your problem. You need to have a `settings.py` on the same folder as the application, or you need to pass the `settings` path to the app.

See the Eve docs [here](http://python-eve.org/config.html#configuration-with-files) for a detailed explanation of configuration with files.

Answer (score 0):

The error `ConfigException: DOMAIN dictionary missing or wrong.` is very misleading.
When I run into such errors, I debug the `validate_domain_struct` in flaskapp.py, by stepping thru it line by line. This has **always** helped me find the root cause.

Which version of eve are you using ?
https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/issues/823 says it is fixed in eve 0.6+