# mod_wsgi apache with python-eve

Tags: eve

I tried to integrate my `eve` app into `apache`.
I think I did all correctly like it is shown in flask documentation.

When I try to consume my `eve` collection...I get an error in apache log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/customers/webs/myapp/myapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
from run import app as application
File "/var/customers/webs/myapp/run.py", line 9, in <module>
app = Eve(__name__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 139, in __init__
self.validate_domain_struct()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 252, in validate_domain_struct
raise ConfigException('DOMAIN dictionary missing or wrong.')
ConfigException: DOMAIN dictionary missing or wrong.
```

It seems that the app can't find my `settings.py`

My apache folder looks like:

```
/myapp
 - myapp.wsgi
 - run.py
 - settings.py
```

if I start it directly using `python run.py`, everythink works fine.

Comment: Could you post the content of myapp.wsgi please? I'm having trouble finding a way to properly setup wsgi with python-eve too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the hint @gcw

the solution is pretty easy:

just give the full path where the settings.py is located to the constructor

```
app = Eve(settings='/var/customers/webs/myapp/settings.py')
```

Comment: Great! You can mark my answer as correct if it solved the problem.

Comment: HI @harald, since I gave you the solution. Isn't my answer the correct one?

Comment: in your answer is a hint to the solution(thanks for that), in mine is the concrete solution, so i think other users will find this answer more useful, because they dont need to go throug the eve documentation.. is this important for you? if yes i can change it to yours

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521156/eve-app-deployment-errors-can-anyone-help-me-to-fix-it/36725390#36725390) answer. You can try to add the `settings.py` path using `settings` named parameter into the `eve` app initialization.

Comment: hi! yes thank you thats why i tagged it just with [eve]

Comment: yeah, I just removed that comment from the answer, it was useless :).